# How does facebook identify the user who is making the requests in the oAuth flow

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have something I want to understand regarding the oAuth flow in facebook.

I have a facebook application.

When I reach my application site directly (**not through facebook**) i.e enter my application site URL in the address bar, I reach my application. Let's say: https://myApp.com/fbApp

On the server side there's the oAuth flow ( sending a request for the "code" parameter and then with the "code" parameter another request for the "user access token").

I wanted to know how does Facebook knows who is the user that is making the request for the "code" parameter.
I noticed that when I'm loged-in to facebook and I'm going to my site directly (as described above) I'm getting the "user access token".

When the first request to facebook is made for the "code" parameter, is their anything else being transferred behind the scenes?

Comment: which sdk are you using? (js, php, etc)

On js just open a popup if you enter the first time (for ask permissions) or when you have no session active (to you log onto facebook). Then if you have an active session it just can ask facebook to get the access token for the active session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the first redirect request to Facebook is made in order to obtain the code parameter, the URI that is used to forward you on to Facebook includes a client id (see https://github.com/jcleblanc/oauth/blob/master/oauth2-php-facebook/index.php line 7). This client id refers back to an application that the site developer has created at https://developers.facebook.com/apps for their site.

After the code parameter is obtained, the site makes an HTTP POST request back to Facebook to exchange the code for an access token.  In this request the client id and client secret are both transferred (see https://github.com/jcleblanc/oauth/blob/master/oauth2-php-facebook/complete.php line 10).  These two keys, the client id and client secret, are the keys that direct reference the application that was created.

I hope that helps,
Jon

Comment: Hi Jon,Thanks for the answer. I know that there two distinct access tokens: 'user access token' and 'app access token'. The 'app access token' is never changed but the 'user access token' changes over time ( the longest time is 60 days). When I make a request for the 'code' parameter, I indeed use the 'client Id' and but this call with THAT parameter is made for EVERY USER who uses the app, right? I get the parameter 'client id' from facebook after I created my application so this parameter is general for ALL USERS, right? unless I'm missing something)